# Why did GRRM spell the name 'Kleronomas' this way?

Tags: the-thousand-worlds, george-r-r-martin, nightflyers

Quoting [*Nightflyers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightflyers):

> When Kleronomas took his survey ship out from Avalon, the volcryn came within ten light-years of him. Kleronomas found many things, but he did not find the volcryn. Not then did he and not on his return to Avalon a lifetime later. When I was a child of three, Kleronomas was dust, as distant and dead as Jesus of Nazareth and the volcryn passed close to Daronne.

'Kleronom**o**s' is a real Greek name of ancient origin; today it mostly exists as a surname. However, George Martin chose to name one of the recurring (and, in my humble opinion, most charming) characters of his early works 'Kleronom**a**s'.

Given how polished and thought-through GRRM's texts are, it's not likely to be a mistake. So, what's the obscure message here?

Comment: Well I haven't read Nightflyers but at least in ASOIAF, George often modifies real world names to make them fit his fantasy world. Like William becomes Willem, Peter becomes Petyr, Edwin becomes Edwyn, Adam becomes Addam, Luther becomes Lothar/Luthor etc

Comment: @Aegon I thing those are not so much modifications of names but choosing spellings from different languages.  The present monarch of the Netherlands is King Willem-Alexander. Peter is Peddyr in Manx and Pedr in Welsh.  Addams is an English family name, a short form of Addamsson,etc. etc..

Comment: @M.A.Golding Sure but Kleronomos ->Kleronomas is after all a play on the spellings as well.